# Dell Latitude D520 Bluetooth won't stay "visible"

Tags: 14.04, dell, bluetooth

I've recently purchased a used Dell Latitude D520 and installed Kubuntu 14.04LTS (I believe it would have upgraded to 14.04.1 after installation).  As far as I've been able to test, everything is working fine (battery, modular bay battery, wifi, hard disk -- haven't tried to check PCMCIA port since the only PC cards I have are 56k modem and ethernet, both of which are built into the machine) -- except that I can't get the internal Bluetooth adapter to stay visible.

I checked in BIOS Setup and verified that the Bluetooth was enabled, but when I go into System Settings, Bluetooth, I get a yellow bar with the message "Your default Bluetooth adapter is not visible for remote devices." and a button with "Fix it"; clicking the button causes the bar to vanish, but has to be done for each of the three setting pages.  Once done, and "Always Visible" selected in Adapters, it'll stay until I close the Bluetooth settings pages and reopen them -- at which point I have the "not visible" message again.

My phone (weeks-old Galaxy 4S, Bluetooth turned on to test this) fails to detect nearby Bluetooth devices even immediately after selecting "Always visible" on the Adapters page.

Do I need a driver, or is there some other problem?

`dmesg | grep Bluetooth
[   19.128885] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17
[   19.129047] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   19.129061] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   19.129065] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   19.129071] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   22.579616] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   22.579633] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   22.579647] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   22.632540] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   22.632545] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   22.632561] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
dqualls@Latitude:~$`

This looks as if Kubuntu knows there's Bluetooth present, at least.